# Scope of @@rowcount?

Tags: sql-server, rowcount

What is the scope of `@@rowcount` ?[MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) doesn't mention its scope.

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

Ok.

In my SP —  I'm inserting into a table , which has a `insert trigger` which does *another* insertion when a new value is inserted to the table.

**Question:**

To which scope the `@@rowcount` will refer ? (trigger or SP) ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Granted, the article is for SQL Server 2000, but one would hope the scope doesn't change between versions.  According to the article [How triggers affect ROWCOUNT and IDENTITY in SQL Server 2000](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/23/rowcount-and-identity/), `@@ROWCOUNT` will not be affected by triggers.

Specifically:

> It’s safe to use @@ROWCOUNT in SQL Server 2000 even when there is a trigger on the base table. The trigger will not skew your results; you’ll get what you expect. @@ROWCOUNT works correctly even when NOCOUNT is set.

So if you update three rows, and the trigger updates five rows elsewhere, you'll get a `@@ROWCOUNT` of 3.

Also, from GBN's answer in [SQL Server - is using @@ROWCOUNT safe in multithreaded applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960510/sql-server-is-using-rowcount-safe-in-multithreaded-applications):

> @@ROWCOUNT is both scope and connection safe.
>
> In fact, it reads only the last statement row count for that connection and scope.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!

Answer (score 12):

every insert/update/select/set/delete statement resets the `@@rowcount` to the rows affected by the executed statement

```
begin
declare @myrowcount int,
    @myrowcount2 int
insert stmt
SET @myrowcount=@@rowcount
if @myrowcount>0
begin
insert stmt
SET @myrowcount2 =@@rowcount
if @myrowcount2 >0
do smthg
end
end
```

or  try this

```
 SELECT * FROM master.sys.objects -- 50 rows
    IF (1=1)
        SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS RowsAffected -- 0, because the IF did not affect any rows
```

even an IF statement affects it....hence its scope is the last statement read.