# How @@rowcount works if two queries executed simultaneously in two query windows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use `@@rowcount` to track rows processed. But I have question if one statement is executed and taking long time, meanwhile if other query executed in other query window will it affect `@@rowcount` value of first one?

How `@@rowcount` will behave in this scenario?

Database: SQL Server

Comment: What happens when you try it in two windows?

Comment: When I'm trying it is giving expected output but I want to use this with dynamic query,So wanted to know firm detail on same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server - is using @@ROWCOUNT safe in multithreaded applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960510/sql-server-is-using-rowcount-safe-in-multithreaded-applications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will give the corresponding rows affected for the two queries. Two windows here, are effectively two sessions. So they are not affected in any way whatsoever.

`@@ROWCOUNT` is both scope and connection safe.

In fact, it reads only the last statement row count for that connection and scope. The full rules are here on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) (cursors, `DML`, `EXECUTE` etc)

To use it in subsequent statements, you need to store it in a local variable.

Comment: But @@rowcount is global variable. So you are saying every session will have it's own copy?

Comment: @ADITYAPAWAR I have expanded my answer. Hope it answers your question.